# Sudden collapse of kableExtra in [R]

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I should probably point out that I am still fairly new to working with `RMarkdown` and the `kableExtra` R package, but I have a document that was knitable last week and now no longer knits despite no physical changes to the document.  The error message I receive is the following

**Error in save_kable_latex(x, file, latex_header_includes, keep_tex) : We hit an error when trying to use magick to read the generated PDF file.  You may check your magick installation and try to use the magick::image_read to read the PDF file manually.  It's also possible that you didn't have ghostscript installed.  Calls  ...  -> as_image -> save_kable -> save_kable_latex  Execution halted**

I have tried everything that I can think of by re-installing the `magick` R package, installing ghostscript (through Homebrew), etc.

And the code chunk given below seems to be where the issues are occurring, where `tab2` is a data frame with some of its elements being a LaTeX expressions such as `"\\sum_x f(x)*\\left ( pe(x) - lcl(x) \\right )"`.

```
kable( tab2, format="latex", escape=FALSE, align="c", col.names=NULL ) %>%
  kable_styling( latex_options=c('hold_position') ) %>%
  footnote( general="Given x successes out of n trials, the holistic Jeffreys $100*(1-\\\\alpha)\\\\%$ Lower $\\\\textit{Credible}$ Limit is the value $p$ such that $\\\\int_0^p \\\\frac{t^{x+0.5-1}(1-t)^{n-x+0.5-1}}{B(x+0.5,n-x+0.5)} dt = \\\\alpha$ where B(a,b) is the Beta function given by $\\\\int_0^1 t^{(x-1)}(1-t)^{(y-1)} dt$.",
           general_title="", threeparttable = TRUE,
            footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, escape=FALSE ) %>%
  as_image( file="tab2.png", width=8, units="in" )
```

and printed to the PDF later on using the `include_graphics()` function on a new slide.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as this is for a work presentation.

**EDIT #1**

As requested, here is a Minimum Working Example

```
prob.success <- sample( seq(.5,.99,.01), size=1 )
conf.alpha <- sample( seq(.5,.99,.01), size=1 )

tab1 <- data.frame( x=0:5, f=round(dbinom(0:5,5,prob.success),3) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=x/5, lcl=qbeta(1-conf.alpha,x+0.5,5-0:5+0.5) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=pmin(pe,lcl) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=pe-lcl ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=f*delta )

exp.expr <- "\\sum_x f(x)*\\left ( pe(x) - lcl(x) \\right )"
exp.delta <- format( round(sum( tab1$f_delta ),4), nsmall=4 )

tab2 <- tab1 %>%
  mutate( x=as.character(x), f=format(round(f,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=format(round(pe,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=format(round(lcl,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=format(round(delta,4),nsmall=3) ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=format(round(f_delta,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="",f_delta="") ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="", f="", pe="Exp", lcl="Diff", delta="=", f_delta=exp.expr) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="=",f_delta=exp.delta) ) %>%
  rbind( data.frame(x="x",f="f(x)",pe="pe(x)",lcl="lcl(x)",delta="pe(x)-lcl(x)",
                    f_delta="f(x)\\times\\left(pe(x)-lcl(x)\\right)"), . )
```

**EDIT #2**

And these are the R packages used in the .Rmd file

```
library( knitr )
library( tibble )
library( magrittr )
library( dplyr )
library( kableExtra )
library( stringr )
library( magick )
```

Comment: Can you give as your data `tab2`? Without that it will be very complicated to find your root of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several emails with the `kableExtra` author Hao Zhu, it was suggested that a HTML table (instead of LaTeX) should be used.  As a result, the following code was able to render successfully.  Many thanks to Hao.

Changes to the original post include

```
exp.expr <- "$\\sum_x f(x)*\\left ( pe(x) - lcl(x) \\right )$"
```

```
tab2 <- tab1 %>%
  mutate( x=as.character(x), f=format(round(f,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=format(round(pe,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=format(round(lcl,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=format(round(delta,4),nsmall=3) ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=format(round(f_delta,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
#  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="",f_delta="") ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="", f="", pe="Exp", lcl="Diff", delta="=", f_delta=exp.expr) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="=",f_delta=exp.delta) ) # %>%
#  rbind( data.frame(x="x",f="f(x)",pe="pe(x)",lcl="lcl(x)",delta="pe(x)-lcl(x)",
#                    f_delta="f(x)\\times\\left(pe(x)-lcl(x)\\right)"), . )
```

```
tab.cols <- c( "x", "f(x)", "pe(x)", "lcl(x)", "pe(x)-lcl(x)",
                "$f(x)\\times\\left(pe(x)-lcl(x)\\right)$" )
```

```
kable( tab2, format="html", escape=FALSE, align="c", col.names=tab.cols ) %>%
  kable_styling( "striped", full_width = F, position="center" ) %>%
  footnote( general="Given x successes out of n trials, the holistic Jeffreys $100*(1-\\alpha)\\%$ Lower *Credible* Limit is the value $p$ such that $\\int_0^p \\frac{t^{x+0.5-1}(1-t)^{n-x+0.5-1}}{B(x+0.5,n-x+0.5)} dt = \\alpha$ where B(a,b) is the Beta function given by $\\int_0^1 t^{(x-1)}(1-t)^{(y-1)} dt$.",
           general_title="Note:", footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, escape=FALSE )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed the `$` marks in your table.

```
prob.success <- sample( seq(.5,.99,.01), size=1 )
conf.alpha <- sample( seq(.5,.99,.01), size=1 )

tab1 <- data.frame( x=0:5, f=round(dbinom(0:5,5,prob.success),3) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=x/5, lcl=qbeta(1-conf.alpha,x+0.5,5-0:5+0.5) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=pmin(pe,lcl) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=pe-lcl ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=f*delta )

exp.expr <- "$\\sum_x f(x)*\\left ( pe(x) - lcl(x) \\right )$"  # <- Here
exp.delta <- format( round(sum( tab1$f_delta ),4), nsmall=4 )

tab2 <- tab1 %>%
  mutate( x=as.character(x), f=format(round(f,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=format(round(pe,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=format(round(lcl,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=format(round(delta,4),nsmall=3) ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=format(round(f_delta,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="",f_delta="") ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="", f="", pe="Exp", lcl="Diff", delta="=", f_delta=exp.expr) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="=",f_delta=exp.delta) ) %>%
  rbind( data.frame(x="x",f="f(x)",pe="pe(x)",lcl="lcl(x)",delta="pe(x)-lcl(x)",
                    f_delta="$f(x)\\times\\left(pe(x)-lcl(x)\\right)$"), . )  # <- And here
```

Comment: Adding in the four $ as you described still doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: So based on some emails with Hao, this seems to be an r issues (and not latex) as I am unable to fully complete each of the r chunks within the document.  Commenting out the as_image line seems to allot the .rmd file to knit properly.

However, I am unable to get the table to work properly when placed into an r chunk instead of using the include_graphics() command.