# Removing the full width of a kableExtra table using a popover

Tags: r-markdown, popover, kableextra

Continuing with the answer to a previous SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343132/sudden-collapse-of-kableextra-in-r/61535929#61535929), the resulting table is occupying the entire width of a `slidy_presentation` despite the command `kable_styling(full_width=F)` being utilized.  As I am still new to the `kableExtra` package and `RMarkdown` as a whole, I have a feeling it might be due to the long footnote at the bottom of the table.

As a result, I am trying to utilize the HTML "popover" feature as suggested in the R vignette [Awesome Table in HTML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#popover_message).  In particular, I am trying to create a "Note" field in the last row of the `x` column from the following .RMD file.

**RMD file:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"  
output: slidy_presentation  
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
```

Include the HTML script from vignette here.

```{r echo=FALSE}
prob.success <- sample( seq(.5,.99,.01), size=1 )
conf.alpha <- sample( seq(.5,.99,.01), size=1 )

tab1 <- data.frame( x=0:5, f=round(dbinom(0:5,5,prob.success),3) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=x/5, lcl=qbeta(1-conf.alpha,x+0.5,5-0:5+0.5) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=pmin(pe,lcl) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=pe-lcl ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=f*delta )

exp.expr <- "$\\sum_x f(x)*\\left ( pe(x) - lcl(x) \\right )$"
exp.delta <- format( round(sum( tab1$f_delta ),4), nsmall=4 )

tab2 <- tab1 %>%
  mutate( x=as.character(x), f=format(round(f,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=format(round(pe,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=format(round(lcl,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=format(round(delta,4),nsmall=3) ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=format(round(f_delta,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
rbind( ., data.frame(x="", f="", pe="Exp", lcl="Diff", delta="=", f_delta=exp.expr) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="",f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="=",f_delta=exp.delta) )

tab.cols <- c( "x", "f(x)", "pe(x)", "lcl(x)", "pe(x)-lcl(x)",
            "$f(x)\\times\\left(pe(x)-lcl(x)\\right)$" )

kable( tab2, format="html", escape=FALSE, align="c", col.names=tab.cols ) %>%
  kable_styling( "striped", full_width = F, position="center" ) %>%
  footnote( general="Given x successes out of n trials, the holistic Jeffreys $100*(1-\\alpha)\\%$ Lower *Credible* Limit is the value $p$ such that $\\int_0^p \\frac{t^{x+0.5-1}(1-t)^{n-x+0.5-1}}{B(x+0.5,n-x+0.5)} dt = \\alpha$ where B(a,b) is the Beta function given by $\\int_0^1 t^{(x-1)}(1-t)^{(y-1)} dt$.",
       general_title="Note:", footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, escape=FALSE )
````

**My attempt thus far**

With the only change to the R chunk above being with the variable `tab2`, here is what I have tried.

```
tab2 <- tab1 %>%
  mutate( x=as.character(x), f=format(round(f,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( pe=format(round(pe,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( lcl=format(round(lcl,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  mutate( delta=format(round(delta,4),nsmall=3) ) %>%
  mutate( f_delta=format(round(f_delta,4),nsmall=4) ) %>%
  rbind( ., data.frame(x="", f="", pe="Exp", lcl="Diff", delta="=", f_delta=exp.expr) ) %>%
  # Change is only with the last line
  rbind( ., data.frame(x=cell_spec("Note",popover=spec_popover(content="Test",title=NULL,position="bottom")),
                       f="",pe="",lcl="",delta="=",f_delta=exp.delta) )
```

and the popover feature doesn't work.

Comment: Fast Workaround: Indeed, the footnote is too long. Add `<br>` in your footnote text to make a manual line break.

Comment: Thanks @J_F for the workaround.  A little problematic in that the placement of the `<br>` had to be done via trial and error, but as least it does shrink the width of the table.  I'm still hoping that a popover solution is feasible.

Comment: I tried the example from the docu and it didn´t work. So I searched and found [this](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/92). I think it´s not possible until now the issue was never solved. Using `html_document` as output works fine.

Comment: It might have been when I was changing variables around.  The full .Rmd file I am using (with work specific names) is sensitive in nature, so I was changing them to be able to post something.  I will work on creating a single .Rmd file with the changed variable and update the original post.

Comment: @J_F, can you elaborate on "it didn't work"?

Comment: I tried the example from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#popover_message) once with `slidy_presentation` as output file (failed) and once with `html_document` (works) and the issue I linked above confirms these findings.

Comment: I see.  I guess it is just a wishlist item for now then as I also was not able to replicate the vignette example using `slidy_presentation`, but it did work with `html_document` as you pointed out.